# WritableBitmap does not work on separate Thread?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I've got a WritableBitmap that updates on a separate thread, specifically in response to an event.

```
myWritableBitmap.Lock();
CopyMemory(myWritableBitmap.BackBuffer, ...);
myWritableBitmap.AddDirtyRect(...);
myWritableBitmap.Unlock();
```

When run on a separate thread as-is, the `Lock()` command throws a `System.InvalidOperationException`.

If I run the same code like this:

```
this.Dispatcher.Invoke(new VoidDelegate(delegate
{
  //Same code as above...
}));
```

No exceptions are thrown and the code runs perfectly. Wouldn't the purpose of the Lock() be to allow multi-threaded access? Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many of the WPF drawing functions must run in a STAThread. The second piece of code makes your drawing functions run in the main UI thread.

Edit: A little bit more about threading in WPF found [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/dwayneneed/archive/2007/04/26/multithreaded-ui-hostvisual.aspx).

Comment: The lock shouldn't be doing any drawing though. I would assume I could copy the memory to the back buffer and then it would be drawn on the UI thread.

Comment: I think the case is that it is that much of the drawing functionality found in WPF uses some COM-based code - which needs to be called from the a STAThread.

Comment: Would this mean I could spawn the above code on a new thread with Apartment = STA?